# Ubuntu 22.04 Live did not find my RAID0

Tags: gparted, raid

I configured RAID0 on my machine with Auros Z390 mainboard:

[image]

and was able to use it on Windows 10:

[image]

I am not sure if it is really possible, but at least I thought that I probably copy my old SATA SSD Windows 10 system drive to my new RAID Ubuntu 22.04 Live, but it did not find my RAID:

[image]

[image]

See all the steps I did and more pictures [here](https://developernote.com/2024/03/configuring-raid-on-auros-z390-mainboard/).